# Como faço para colocar dois paineis no layout com fancybox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

Tudo bem?
Estou com um problema ao utilizar o fancybox no meu portifolio, estou criando uma parte aonde tera meus projetos já criados, e estou querendo que quando o usuario clicar em algum dos projetos, aparece as imagens do projeto e um texto do lado falando sobre, o titulo e um link do repositorio. Estou utilizando a biblioteca fancybox para isso, e ussando de inspiração esse layout https://fancyapps.com/playground/vp.

```
 <div class="projeto">

                <a data-name="costs"
                data-fancybox="costs" 
                href="images/Costs/img-1.png" 
                class="fancybox">
                    <img class="rounded" src="images/Costs/img-1.png">
                </a>
                
                <div style="display:none">
                    <a data-fancybox="costs" href="images/Costs/img-2.png" class="fancybox">
                        <img class="rounded" src="images/Costs/img-2.png">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="costs" href="images/Costs/img-3.png" class="fancybox">
                        <img class="rounded" src="images/Costs/img-3.png">
                    </a>
                </div>

            <div 
            class="hidden gallery-data">
                <div id="costs">
                    <h2>Costs</h2>
                    <p>Costs é uma aplicação web de organização financeira para empresas e pessoas. Com ele, é possível controlar e gerenciar gastos, criar orçamentos e acompanhar suas finanças de maneira simples e intuitiva. Utilizando dados armazenados em formato json, sendo construido em React, com a funcão de react-router-dom, para facilitar a nevegação entre as paginas.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="projeto">

            <a data-name="filmes_lib"
            data-fancybox="filmes_lib" 
            href="images/Filmes_Lib/img-1.png" 
            class="fancybox">
                <img class="rounded" src="images/Filmes_Lib/img-1.png">
            </a>
            
            <div style="display:none">
                <a data-fancybox="filmes_Lib" href="images/Filmes_Lib/img-2.png" class="fancybox">
                    <img class="rounded" src="images/Filmes_Lib/img-2.png">
                </a>
                <a data-fancybox="filmes_Lib" href="images/Filmes_Lib/img-3.png" class="fancybox">
                    <img class="rounded" src="images/Filmes_Lib/img-3.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div 
            class="hidden gallery-data filmes_lib">
                <div id="filmes_lib">
                    <h2>Filmes_Lib</h2>
                    <p>Filmes_lib é um aplicativo web que apresenta cartazes de filmes e suas avaliações. Com ele, é possível descobrir novos filmes, ler resenhas e verificar classificações. Utilizando a API do TMDB, temos acesso a uma grande variedade de filmes e informações atualizadas, feito em React.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

// FANCYAPPS

        Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', {
            hideClass: false,
            closeButton: "top",
            dragToClose: false,
            Toolbar: false,
            Thumbs: false,
            Carousel: {
                Navigation: true,
                Dots: true,
            },

            on: {
                initLayout: (fancybox) => {
                // Create main container for left panel and Fancybox carousel
                const $mainPanel = document.createElement("div");
                $mainPanel.classList.add("fancybox__main-panel");

                // Create left panel
                const $leftPanel = document.createElement("div");
                $leftPanel.classList.add("fancybox__left-panel");

                const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-data");

                for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                $leftPanel.innerHTML += elements[i].innerHTML;
                }

                const idText = $leftPanel.querySelectorAll("[id]");

                    idText.forEach(function(element) {

                        const fancyboxLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".projeto a[data-name]");

                        for (let i = 0; i < fancyboxLinks.length; i++) {

                            if (fancyboxLinks[i].getAttribute("data-name") === element.getAttribute("id")) {
                                $mainPanel.appendChild($leftPanel);
                                $mainPanel.appendChild(fancybox.$carousel);
                                fancybox.$backdrop.after($mainPanel);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                            
                },
            },
        });
```

estou tendo o problema nesse javascript, pq eu quero que cada projeto tenha seu texto unico, mas toda vida que eu clico em qualquer um dos projetos, os dois texto `gallery-data` aparece juntos, e não estou conseguindo fazer que cada texto va para seu projeto, dps eu vou querer colocar outros projetos. Teria alguma maneira para isso?[está ficando assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hKW3.png)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o método "beforeShow" do fancybox e adicionar dinamicamente o painel de descrição do projeto ao lado do painel de imagens. Como por exemplo:

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox]', {
  hideClass: false,
  closeButton: "top",
  dragToClose: false,
  Toolbar: false,
  Thumbs: false,
  Carousel: {
    Navigation: true,
    Dots: true,
  },
  beforeShow: (instance) => {
    // Obter o id do projeto atual
    const projectId = instance.opts.$orig[0].nextElementSibling.children[0].id;

    // Criar um painel de descrição para o projeto atual
    const $descPanel = document.createElement("div");
    $descPanel.classList.add("fancybox__desc-panel");
    $descPanel.innerHTML = document.getElementById(projectId).innerHTML;

    // Adicionar painel de descrição ao lado do painel de imagens
    instance.$refs.container.appendChild($descPanel);
  }
});
```

Nesse exemplo acima, o método "beforeShow" é chamado antes de mostrar o fancybox e nele é adicionado dinamicamente o painel de descrição do projeto ao lado do painel de imagens. O id do projeto atual é obtido da seguinte maneira: instance.opts.$orig[0].nextElementSibling.children[0].id. Depois disso, é criado um novo elemento div para conter a descrição do projeto e esse elemento é adicionado ao fancybox usando o método appendChild.

Comment: mas eu estou utilizando a versao 4 do fancybox, nessa versão não tem mais o beforeShow: (instance)